# React-Map-GL - Can't pass environmental variable to component

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, mapbox, react-map-gl

I'm using `react-map-gl` to integrate Mapbox into my project. My Map component looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';

function Map() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    latitude: 37.7577,
    longitude: -122.4376,
    zoom: 8
  });

  return (
    <ReactMapGL
      {...viewport}
      mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_KEY}
      onViewportChange={nextViewport => setViewport(nextViewport)}
    />
  );
}

export default Map;
```

I'm getting a "no token warning" and my map doesn't display. If I swap out `process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_KEY` with the actual string key it works fine. Why can't I use a variable in my `.env` file and pass it to mapboxApiAccessToken?

In my `.env` file my key variable looks like this:
REACT_APP_MAPBOX_KEY=the actual string here

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: have you restarted the project after adding the env variable?

Comment: Restarted and it worked. Major facepalm. Thanks a lot, that was driving me crazy.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: @IdrissAITHAFID do you know what's the issue if it is something in production? I have a similar issue on Heroku. the project works great on my dev environment but in production it show NO_TOKEN_WARNING. I have set up the config/prod.js daily simple. such as  `module.exports = {
    REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN: process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN,
}`

Comment: what are the names of .env files you have? you may have only set it on .env.development

Answer (score 0):

Do not use process.env it not work for react-map-gl direct paste token it works fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).