# ENV processing not working in NextJS & Mapbox

Tags: next.js, mapbox, react-map-gl

quick question. I'm trying to use NextJS with Mapbox and having a weird issue with the env processing with Next.

So I have a .env.local file with a few variables:

```
DATABASE_URL="file:./dev.db"
WP_API_URL=
MAPBOX_KEY=
```

Now anytime I call these variables in anything else except for Mapbox they work fine. However, if I try to call it in mapbox like the following:

```
export default function Map() {
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%"
  });

  return (
   
        <ReactMapGL
          mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.MAPBOX_KEY}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11"
          {...viewport}
          onViewportChange={(nextViewport) => setViewport(nextViewport)}
        ></ReactMapGL>
    
  );
}
```

It doesn't work. Strangely, if I call a console.log in that function it *does* return the right string of the env and doesn't say undefined. So i'm at a total loss and hoping some of you can help. I did some investigation here on SO and saw another person with this error saying that dotenv messed with the processing, but I don't have dotenv installed in this project ([Environment variable not working with Mapbox token on NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64110434/environment-variable-not-working-with-mapbox-token-on-nextjs)).

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to [expose env variables to the browser](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

Comment: Tried that too, same errors :(

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63143425/react-map-gl-cant-pass-environmental-variable-to-component solve your problem

Comment: No :( I still get "Invariant Violation: accessToken required to instantiate Mapbox client"

Comment: Edit..I think that did it! thanks :)